# How to handle and log error in Javascript in Large SPA

Tags: javascript, php

I am new to Javascript ,  I was wonder like we log error in Server Side programming language in a error.log file . for example in PHP there we can set a error file to log the errors .

Is there a way to do this in Large SPA in Javascript or we just log in console using

`console.log()`

I have this simple [app](http://vikramide.github.io/jasonExample.html#) which loads some json data from API and I have just used the normal alert and `console.log` methods to show error I would like to know whats the best way to do this.

I understand that I can write a `Web Service` which can be called every time an error being thrown and using the

`window.error` or `element.error` function probably I can send error report to the server where I will write on a log file.

But is Doing rest call on every error thrown is a good way?

Thanks

Comment: Your idea of logging using ajax call in server, has an issue if it fails in transport layer otherwise it is good to permanently save error logs in server. Have a look on this link http://log4javascript.org/docs/quickstart.html

Comment: @GauravP any other Robust options , Not plugin Dependent  I am trying to learn JS, I would like to build something on scratch to just get an Idea How to handle errors in Large Js Projects

Answer (score 2):

Browsers won't allow you to write on a file in client so You have to use ajax and write a log on server.
Sending errors to server using ajax is a good solution.
Also throwing error with alert is not appreciated by any user.